# Как передать информацию из класса Main в другой класс java

Tags: java

вот класс Main, в него пользователь вносит свои данные

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your login: ");
        String login = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        int age = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your hobbies: ");
        String hobbies1 = scan.nextLine();
        String hobbies = scan.nextLine();
```

мне необходимо из этого класса передать данные в этот конструктор, который примет все данные от пользователя

```
public class Scanning extends Main {
  public Scanning(){}
  public Scanning(String name, String login, int age, List<String> hobbies){
  }
}
```

я не понимаю как это сделать, я еще совсем новичек, так что не бейте, если тут все супер просто)

Comment: в java 14+ так можно описывать record. Например, `public record Scanning(String name, String login, int age, List<String> hobbies) {}`. Конструктор, методы доступа к полям, toString, hash и equals создадутся автоматически. А вот `extends Main` не стоит делать, т.к. `Scanning` вовсе не Main-класс. И ещё, стоит или попросить ввести его хобби через разделитель (например, запятую), либо сразу указать ему число хобби.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все правильно делаете, осталось добавить поля класса и инициализировать их.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your login: ");
        String login = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
        Integer age = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your hobbies: ");
        String hobbies1 = scan.nextLine();
        String hobbies2 = scan.nextLine();
        
        Scanning scanning = new Scanning(name, login, age, hobbies1, hobbies2);
        
    }
}

public class Scanning {
    
    private String name;
    private String login;
    private Integer age;
    private List<String> hobbies;

    public Scanning(String name, String login, Integer age, String ... hobbies) {
        this.name = name;
        this.login = login;
        this.age = age;
        this.hobbies = Arrays.asList(hobbies);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь скорее всего вам нет необходимости писать `extends Main` т.к. это наследование, а оно вам вероятно не особо тут поможет.

В вашем классе Scanning присутствует 2 конструктора, один пустой (`public Scanning(){}`), другой принимающий параметры (`public Scanning(String name, String login, int age, List<String> hobbies){}`).
Для передачи данных в другой класс мы будем использовать второй.

Что бы вызвать конструктор, нужно создать экземпляр интересующего нас класса и передать ему параметры, которые требует второй конструктор, для этого создадим лист и запишем в него наши хобби (т.к. в вашем втором конструкторе требуется лист):

```
List hobbies = new LinkedList();
hobbies.add(hobbies1);
hobbies.add(hobbies2);
```

Теперь вызовем конструктор, создав новый экземпляр и передав необходимые данные:

```
Scanning scanning = new Scanning(name, login, age, hobbies);
```

Готово, мы передали данные в конструктор класса `Scanning`

**UPD:**

Так же мы можем поменять конструктор, как показал [@Дмитрий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/269255/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) в своем сообщении на:

```
public Scanning(String name, String login, Integer age, String ... hobbies)
```

Что бы он принимал набор строчек, тогда не будет необходимости создавать лист перед передачей данных, однако обратите внимание, что потом вам будет всеж нужно его обработать